# How do I change the default LED pin for displaying uploading

Tags: arduino-ide, led

I made a board for my project based on Arduino Pro Mini. The problem is, that I had to put the LED on pin 4 instead of pin 13.

What setting do I have to change to make pin 4 the default one? Or do I have to write my own Board Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blinking while uploading makes the bootloader. Arduino Mini uses Optiboot. The source codes are [on GitHub](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/blob/master/optiboot/bootloaders/optiboot/pin_defs.h). You would need to change the pin in pin_defs.h and make the bootloader. Then flash it to the 328p with a programmer over ICSP.

Details what to change are in [Greenonline's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/how-do-i-change-the-default-led-pin-for-displaying-uploading#answer-55282).

Answer (score 2):

Following on from [Juraj's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/how-do-i-change-the-default-led-pin-for-displaying-uploading#answer-55280):

> The blinking while uploading makes the bootloader. Arduino Mini uses
>   Optiboot. The source codes are [on GitHub](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/blob/master/optiboot/bootloaders/optiboot/pin_defs.h). You would need to
>   change the pin in pin_defs.h and make the bootloader. Then flash it to
>   the 328p with a programmer over ICSP.

The line that you need to change in [`pin_defs.h`](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/blob/master/optiboot/bootloaders/optiboot/pin_defs.h) is [line number 27](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/blob/master/optiboot/bootloaders/optiboot/pin_defs.h#L27):

```
#define LED B5
```

As you can see it is currently set to `B5`. This is the fifth bit in port B which corresponds to pin 13

Pin 4 corresponds to `PORTD` bit 4, so the line would become

```
#define LED D4
```

The Arduino digital pins are connected to three different banks of 8 bits, known as *ports* (`PORTD`, `PORTB` and PORTC`). To see their relation, refer to this table from [Arduino Playground - Pins](https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Pins)

> [image: Ports to Pins table]

Comment: I copied my answer as intro into this answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not sure it was necessary, unless you planned on deleting your answer. However, I've added a link back to yours to reference the quote, and it makes a bit more sense that way. Thanks again :-).